# Python Decimal module doesn't work on uint64

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I'm trying to convert a numpy.uint64 (which is outputted by numpy.sum()) to a decimal without losing precision with the Decimal module.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> sum = np.sum(1000000000000000000)
>>> type(sum)
<type 'numpy.int64'>
>>> Decimal(sum)
Decimal('1000000000000000000')
>>>
>>> sum = np.sum(1000000000000000000000)
>>> type(sum)
<type 'long'>
>>> Decimal(sum)
Decimal('1000000000000000000000')
>>>
>>> sum = np.sum(10000000000000000000)
>>> type(sum)
<type 'numpy.uint64'>
>>> Decimal(sum)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 657, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)
TypeError: Cannot convert 10000000000000000000 to Decimal
```

Comment: I encounter error even for the first conversion: `TypeError: conversion from numpy.int64 to Decimal is not supported` in Python3.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decimal.Decimal` doesn't understand NumPy inputs, so convert the `numpy.uint64` to a Python scalar with the [`item` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) before calling `decimal.Decimal`:

```
Decimal(np.sum(whatever).item())
```

Comment: Using numpy 1.16 in Python 2.7, `decimal.Decimal` can handle `numpy.int64` and `numpy.float64`, but fails on `numpy.uint64`. In Python 3.6 it can still handle `numpy.float64`, but fails on both integer types.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just upgraded from pandas 0.20.3 to 0.21 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast it to a float before converting to Decimal:

`Decimal(float(sum))`