# Decimal module is not working with Numpy or Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, decimal

I want to use Decimal module.

```
getcontext().prec = 3
d1 = Decimal("0.1")
a = float(0.20052)
b = str(a)
d2 = Decimal(b)
q = d1+d2
print(q) ###0.301
```

and

```
getcontext().prec = 1
d1 = Decimal("0.1")
a = float(0.20052)
b = str(a)
d2 = Decimal(b)
q = d1+d2
print(q)##0.3
```

is working.

However, the codes below is not working. I want "0.0."

```
np.random.seed(12345678)  #fix random seed to get the same result
n1 = 200  # size of first sample
n2 = 300  # size of second sample
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n1, loc=0., scale=1)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=n2, loc=0.5, scale=1.5)

print(stats.mannwhitneyu(rvs1, rvs2))###MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=25639.0, pvalue=0.0029339910470636116)
p_value = stats.mannwhitneyu(rvs1, rvs2).pvalue
print(p_value)###0.0029339910470636116
p_str = str(p_value)
getcontext().prec = 1
p_n = Decimal(p_str)
print(p_n)###0.0029339910470636116
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214243/python-decimal-module-doesnt-work-on-uint64) and used item method, but the result has not changed. I want "0.0029."

```
getcontext().prec = 4
p2 = Decimal(p_value.item())
print(p2)####0.0029339910470636116311682339841127031832002103328704833984375
```

MacOS 10.14.5; python 3.7.2; jupyter notebook 4.4.0; numpy 1.17.2; scipy 1.2.1

In addition, I want "0.0029" but the results are shown below.

```
getcontext().prec = 4
p_n = Decimal(p_str)
print(p_n)##0.0029339910470636116
p_n = Decimal(p_str) + 0
print(p_n)##0.002934
p_n = Context(prec=4).create_decimal(p_str)+0
print(p_n)##0.002934
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative comment. I tried and got "0.002934." I want to get "0.0029."

Comment: **However, the codes below is not working.**.  That phrase should be banned in SO.  If there's an error, describe it in full.  If the results are not what you expect, show both those results and the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the result has not changed.

There is a conceptual gap, here.

Changing `prec` of the current [context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.getcontext)
changes how e.g. `__add__( ... )` behaves.
It does not change how the constructor behaves -- if you supply a
high precision input the ctor will still offer a high precision output.
Consider this demo:

```
>>> getcontext().prec = 1
>>> 
>>> Decimal('.12345') 
Decimal('0.12345')
>>> 
>>> Decimal('.12345') + 0
Decimal('0.1')
```

And naturally, the `prec` attribute has no effect at all on
unrelated math packages that use IEEE-754 FP operations, such as numpy.
If `p_value` has many digits of precision,
then it is unsurprising that `Decimal(p_value)`
will report many digits of precision.
Perhaps you'd like to add `0` to that?

Comment: Thank you. I have to change my question. Please wait for a few hours.